# Create User Using ASP.NET Membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

When I create a user using membership in asp.net, after successfully create user it get automatically login to the system. But I don't want to login immediately. Can someone help me?

Comment: Make sure your question includes. 1) Current input  2) Code snippets you have tried 3) Expected output 4) error messages if getting any.   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set LoginCreatedUser property to false.
For example,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Replace createUserWizard1 with ID of your CreateUserWizard control.
    createUserWizard1.LoginCreatedUser = false;
}
```